# MongoDB - can read cause write locks?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB database with ~100GB data size. I ran a test with 300 threads and a total 10,000 'read' queries. I notice on the MMS lock% it is showing 0.6 ~ 1% of write lock. My question is, the queries are purely 'read', why is it showing write lock?

Comment: Have you tried running `db.serverStatus()` to get more info on where the locks are occurring?

Comment: Yes, and in MMS I can select which db the lock% was on. write locks occur on db I performed read-only queries. I had db profiler turned on, but that should only write to 'local' database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, to correct the comment: the profiler does not write to the local database, it writes to whatever database you are profiling in the `system.profile` collection.  So if you were reading from database `foo` and had profiling turned on, the collection would be `foo.system.profile`.  You could turn on profiling for the local database, and hence have the profiler write there of course, but it is not a default of any kind.

Then, if you have the profiler enabled, regardless of where it writes too, all writes require a write lock whether they are to the `system.profile` collection or anywhere else. Just because it is getting input internally does not exclude the `system.profile` collection from following the same rules as any other collection on a database.

If you turn the profiler off I would expect the lock to disappear.  There may still be the occasional blip in the global lock percentage in the stats but that is essentially just background noise.